# Python read excel distinguish number type

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have a column in my excel spreadsheet that contains different types of numbers (i.e., Decimal, Currency, Percentage)

I need to read them into my DF in python and know which ones are which.

excel table looks like:

```
Group       Q2_2022      Q3_2022     Q4_2022       Goal        Comments
Team A        25           24            25           24       meets 
Team B        18%         18%           19%          18%       Q4 over
Team C        $200        $225          $218         $220      Q4 under
```

df = pd.read_excel(file_one, Sheet One)

I need df['Goal] to include the symbol if it exists.

So I need to be able to tell which rows are tracking goals which way.  I do not have any control over the source data.  Is there anyway to do this when I read the data into the python dataframe?

**Edited**
Based on solution by @Timeless below. Headed in the right direction but getting errors.
[image: Error On String]

[image: Values in filed]

Comment: in excel the fields are all numeric, just formatted differently.

Comment: It will format the as strings (object) dtype.

Comment: @AndyReagan, can you show your expected output ?

Comment: My expected output is to actually put 24 in the DF as 24, put 24% into the DF as 24% and put $24 into the DF as $24... I don't care if I bring them in as strings or any other format.  I just need to bring them in with the symbol attached.

Comment: A somewhat complicated way would be to use `win32com` and access the file via COM. You can then use the Range.Text property of each cell to get a string representation of the cell contents. I don't think that is readily accessible via openpyxl or other .xlsx reading engines. For each cell, Excel stores a value, any formula and a number format. It uses the number format at runtime to decide how to display the cell's value on screen. Eg typically the currency character is replaced by the local currency symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this by using [`number_format`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=number_format#using-number-formats) cell's *attribute* from [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl).

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
​
wb = load_workbook("/tmp/file.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
​
data = defaultdict(list)
for row in ws.iter_rows(2):
    for cell, col in zip(row, ws[1]):
        fmt, v1, colname = cell.number_format, cell.value, col.value
        v2 = f"${v1}" if "$" in fmt else f"{v1*100:g}%" if fmt == "0%" else v1
        data[colname].append(v2)
​
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output :

```
​print(df)

   Group Q2_2022 Q3_2022 Q4_2022  Goal
0      1      25      24      25    24
1      2     18%     18%     19%   18%
2      3    $200    $225    $218  $220
```

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for, I'll give it a shot and see if it works.

Comment: so this is on me, but I have additional columns that hold comments, and names.  The code works to do what I need on the numeric fields, but is blowing up on the string fields,  is there a way to ignore the string fields and only evaluate the numeric fields. I apologize for leaving this out of the initial question, I wasn't thinking the issue all the way through. I have edited the question to be a more accurate reflection.

Comment: No worries but I can't reproduce the issue (https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9k7b.png). Can you give a reproducible example and/or the (error?) you got ? What do you mean by _is blowing up on the string fields_ ?

Comment: added screen shots above to show error and values that are being evaluated. Really appreciate the assist

Comment: You're welcome. Here in `f"{v1*100:g}%"`, the `:g` is to get rid of the trailing zeros. Can you try with `f"{v1*100}%"` instead ? It is weird though because the error means that _openpyxl_ is considering a string(?) as a number with a percentage formatting. If you need to push the analyze further, you can add a `try..except` statement to catch up the values (and their Excel coordinates) that may cause an error.